# .bat - Query most recent log file, findstr, then copy the text of the file to the clipboard

Tags: logging, batch-file, findstr

So, I'm often having to check the backup logs of multiple servers, then having to copy and paste the logs into a database. I'm trying to write a .bat that will find the most recent log file, do a FINDSTR to see if the backup is successful, then, if it's successful, copy the text of the log file to the clipboard, if that's even possible. I have all of it hashed out other than the clipboard part, but it isn't working the way I intend it to.

A little bit of needed info -

Each log is saved to the D: drive of the servers. The logs are all named with the following convention: BK(date)-(Backup Set).txt - Example - BK0901-001.txt.

There are also other files commonly in the directory, and are named with the same convention, except with a VY prefix, or they will have a different extension, such as an .xml file - I need to avoid files with any prefix other than BK and all other extensions.

```
@echo off
cd\
cls
set /p busrv=Server? 
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "\\%busrv%\d$\logs\UltraBac\BK*.txt" /B /O:D') DO findstr /I /C:"Completed Without Errors or Warnings."
IF %errorlevel%==0 (COPY TO CLIPBOARD) echo BACKUPS PASSED
IF %errorlevel%==1 echo BACKUPS NOT PASSED
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

If the info is found then it will be on the clipboard, else the clipboard will not be changed.  It's not tested:

```
@echo off
cls
set /p "busrv=Server? "
pushd "\\%busrv%\d$\logs\UltraBac\"
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR "bk*-*.txt" /B /O:D') DO set "file=%%I"
findstr /I /C:"Completed Without Errors or Warnings." "%file%" |clip
popd
pause
```

Comment: another point, with `/o-d` you get the oldest file, not the most recent. The search pattern can be `dir bk*-*.txt` .

Comment: @endoro Thanks for the correction.  Clip.exe is in Vista and later, but I'm not sure what the OP is using.